# Finding Elliptic Curve based on Multiplicity and rational coordinates

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algorithms, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory

We have to find an elliptic curve $E:= y^2=x^3+Ax+B $ (A, B are integers) which has points $P, Q$ with rational coordinates and satisfy $P=[n]Q, n>1$. So,

Input: Rational coordinates = $P$.

Output: Integers $A, B, n$ (when $n>1$), and rational coordinates $Q,$ $$OR,$$

$$Return \; 0.$$

What is the best algorithm or what kind approach should be taken to get the output? is there anything in the literature related to the above problem?

**Note:**

1. **Previously** I thought that it is not needed to assume something about the rational point. For example, if rational point $(x,y)=(p/q,r/2)$ where $q$ and $r$ odd, **then we consider such** $A$ and $B$ **that makes** $x^3 + Ax + B - y^2 = (p^3+Apq^2+Bq^3)/q^3 - r^2/4$ equal $0$, in this case, $(p^3+Apq^2+Bq^3)/q^3 - r^2/4=0 \implies Apq^2+Bq^3 = p^3-r^2\times q^3/4 \cdots$, but it is not true, **in that case, please put necessary and sufficient condition on** $P$, if $P$ does not satisfy that we return $0$.
2. It might not be possible to have such Integers $A, B, n>1, Q$ for a given $P$ satisfying above condition, in that case we return $0.$
3. I am not considering Torsion Group or points of finite order only, $P, Q$ could be points of infinite order.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Fix $P\in E(\mathbb Q)$. Are you asking what percentage of points $Q\in E(\mathbb Q)$ can be written as $[n]P$ for some $n$? If so, what do you main by percentage if $E(\mathbb Q)$ is infinite? Also, surely the answer depends a lot on the choice of $E$ and $P$ – for example if $E(\mathbb Q)\cong \mathbb Z$ and $P$ is chosen to be a generator, the answer will surely be different to if $E(\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z^5$....

Comment: @Mathmo123 let me put it in an input-output problem, if $P$ is given, can you always provide an $E$ where $Q$ is a multiple of $P$ on $E$ where $Q$ has rational x-y components? I was searching an algorithm but could not find, it made me think it is not possible always.

Comment: I'm still confused. Does $P$ have rational coordinates? Is $Q$ fixed?

Comment: @Mathmo123  $P$ has rational coordinates (as written in the post), it is given as input,  $Q$ is the output, thus it is not known or fixed. Also if the question makes sense to you when we consider points on finite order, do consider that case, discarding the infinite order case, thank you.

Comment: The problem is incomplete. Given a rational point $(x,y)=(p/q,r/2)$ where $q$ and $r$ odd, and $A$ and $B$ integer, then $x^3 + Ax + B - y^2 = (p^3+Apq^2+Bq^3)/q^3 - r^2/4$ can never equal $0$. So you need to assume something about the rational point. Otherwise it is not possible to find the curve.

Comment: Even if there are integers $A,B$ such that a given $P$ is on $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$, it is not always possible to get such $E$. For example, if $P(0,1)$ is given, there is no such $E$.

Comment: Your input is a point $P$ with two rational coordinates. Write it with a minimal $d$ as $P(a/d^2, \ b/d^3)$. Then we can find $A,B\in \Bbb Z$ with $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ if( and only i)f we can do so for:$$\frac{b^2-a^3}{d^6} =A\cdot\frac a{d^2}+B\ .$$This depends on the L.H.S. - if it has - after simplifying it - denominator dividing $d^2$, and so that the resulted diophantine equation of degree one in $A,B$ has solutions - then we can. Else not. If we can solve and find $A,B$, i see no point in allowing an $n$ also to be part of an output, why not simply take $n=1$ and $Q=P$ ?!

Comment: @Somos  we find $A, B$ according to $P$, plz check the post again, I have edited.

Comment: @mathlove  if no such curve exists then we return 0, plz check the post again, I have edited.

Comment: @dan_fulea yes, intuitive and primitive way, also take help of  Height Function if we take a brute force approach to try another possible linear equation of $A, B$ anticipating $Q$... but plz note $n=1$ is meaningless, we move on to another case , if there is no such curve, we return $0$, we need the output when $n>1$.

Comment: You are missing something simple. Assume that $A,B,p,q,r$ are integers **and** $q,r$ **both** odd with $(x,y) = (p/q,r/2)$. Then $x^3+Ax+B-y^2 =\frac{4(p^3+Apq^2+Bq^3)-q^3r^2}{4q^3}.$ The numerator is an even integer minus an odd integer and hence can never be zero. So, yes, it is needed to assume something else about the point $(x,y).$

Comment: @Somos I apologize, you are right, sorry for making you write 2 times, regarding the issue you raised, please put necessary and sufficient condition on $P$, if $P$ does not satisfy that we return $0$.

Comment: @mathlove you are correct, I miswrote.

Comment: @consider if your response to mathlove is correct then you are not using the group law on an elliptic curve, considering the tags of this post this seems unlikely?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I should have written $P$ is multiple of  $Q$, according the group law, but I swapped, of-course the problem id based on the group law.

Comment: See also this user's post to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447068/percent-of-rational-coordinates-that-is-a-multiple-of-another-point-on-the-ellip